# Azure data explorer Concurrent queries

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer, azure-load-testing

In azure data explorer, we have made load tests on the cluster with Azure Load testing going through a function app (In consumption tier, function app ) that do request on ADX.

We have never been able to go over 2 concurrent queries . What should we do to go over ? We cannot pass 200 req/s for a simple query.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A couple things could be going on here:

1. The chart is showing the average number of concurrent queries in the time period. If you switch that to show the max concurrent in the time period you'll probably see more (assuming there was actually anything running concurrently.)
2. How long did your queries take to execute? It's possible that Kusto is generally answering your queries faster than they are being submitted. You could check this by using ".show commands-and-queries". Analyze the StartedOn and Duration fields to see how much overlap there really is. If they aren't overlapping, you'll need to modify your load testing app to submit more queries in a shorter amount of time (multithreading, etc.)